# Count alphabets in a crossword game

Tags: ocr

Is there software or an app that can quickly count how many times each alphabet is printed in a crossword game on paper?

Comment: What operating system? What do you mean by 'alphabet' - letters A-Z, or individual letters?

Comment: Do you a mean a *filled in* crossword? And where do you want to start? Do you provide an image to the software, does it have to scan, etc.? And what are you willing to pay for that software. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and [edit] all your answers into your question.